# Fazer CallBack em Having

Tags: mysql, laravel

No Laravel é possível fazer um *callback* no momento de uma consulta.
Por exemplo:

```
$q = Model::where(function($query){
   $query->where(...);
});
```

Gostaria de fazer algo parecido, mas com o *having()*, visto que preciso verificar se determinada variável existe para daí fazer o *having()*.

```
$q = Model::having(function($query){
   if($var)
       $query->having(...);
});
```

Se não existir valor na variável não é para fazer o *having()*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Laravel, alguns métodos de consulta **não aceitam callbacks**.

Parece-me que você está tentando utilizar a mesma funcionalidade existente no `whereSub`, onde você passa uma `Closure` como argumento e, assim, você pode fazer o `if` lá dentro.

Embora dê pra fazer isso, a finalidade do `where` com callback não é fazer ifs, e sim englobar a clausula `where` com parentesis.

No seu caso, acho que você poderia resolver isso com a seguinte manobra: usar o [Model Scope do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes).

```
 class  Model {
     public function scopeClosure($query, \Closure $callback) {
       $callback($query);
       return $query;
     }
 }
```

Daí você faz a consulta assim:

```
Model::where(['nome' => 'Wallace'])->closure(function ($query) use($var) {
       if ($var) $query->having(...);
});
```

Alguns desenvolvedores costumam fazer de uma forma diferente. Costumam "desmembrar" a query, já que o Laravel usa o padrão Fluent Interface. Assim, é possível "continuar" a  query que você atribuiu a uma variável.

```
$query = Usuario::orderBy('nome');

// Executa $query se `$var` é verdadeiro
$var && $query->having(...);

$usuarios = $query->where(['nivel_id' => 4])->paginate(15);
```

## Atualização

Existe no Laravel algumas coisas que você só vai descobrir se você tiver o costume de futucar o código-fonte, como eu costumo fazer.

Acabei de ver uma funcionalidade que foi desenvolvida pensada em casos como o seu, destacado acima. Mas **essa é uma solução exclusiva para quem usa Laravel 5.2**.

Acabei de descobrir que existe um método chamado `when` dentro da classe `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

O código desse método é o seguinte:

```
public function when($value, $callback)
{
    $builder = $this;
    if ($value) {
        $builder = call_user_func($callback, $builder);
    }
    return $builder;
}
```

Link da classe no [GITHUB](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php)

Observando esse método, podemos entender que ele funciona da seguinte forma: Você passa um primeiro argumento para `when`. Se ele for válido, ele executará a query contida dentro da sua `Closure`.

É simples assim:

```
  $idade = 26;

  Usuario::where(['nome' => 'Wallace'])->when($idade > 18, function ($query){
           $query->having(....);
    });
```

Nesse caso acima, para testar o funcionamento, basta alterar o valor de `$idade` para `17`. Tudo que for definido no `callback` de `when` será ignorado.

Comment: Daí dentro da função Closure eu posso colocar o que eu quiser dentro ? Having, Where... ?

Comment: Vou fazer uma ótima atualização agora

Comment: @PeterParker sim, qualquer coisa funciona dentro dessa closure. Mas é melhor você usar o exemplo que eu atualizei. É melhor

Comment: Muito top mesmo. Vai me ajudar nas próximas. Sua solução me ajuda, mas minha query tem algumas particularidades difícil de fazer... e não é difícil, mas o Laravel me dá uns erros que não entendo porquê...

Comment: estou chamando o WHEN, mas diz assim: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::when()

Comment: Não tem essa função WHEN no Laravel 5.1. Enganou eu

Comment: Talvez tenha apenas no 5.2, vou corrigir a informação. Deixei o link do git

Comment: Então vai pelos ares isso ?...

Answer (score 4):

No *Builder* não tem **callback** para o método `having`. Quanto há uma dúvida de geração de um SQL especifica, seria legal colocar em sua pergunta a SQL exemplo, porque, o `having`pode causar diferenças significativas no seu resultado.

Faça um método `scopeWherehaving` (pode ser qualquer nome, mais evite colocar *closure* e *nome reservados*) por exemplo dessa forma:

```
public function scopeWherehaving($query, $value = null)
{
     if (!is_null($value))
     {
         return $query->having('campo', '>', $value);
     }
     return $query;
}
```

Na chamada do seu `Eloquent Builder` faça:

```
Model::wherehaving($value)
```

e continue normalmente a fazer o código.

Dessa forma tem mais clareza e não fica um código muito grande!

Nos links abaixo do próprio Framework fica fácil observar inúmeras formas de trabalhar com ***Query Builder***:

[Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries)

[Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Eu já tinha respondido isso.

Comment: Apesar de estar parecido, vou dar um +1, pois é bom se preocupar com a organização do código :)

Comment: Não briguem, eu positivo todos vocês.